# Failure in establishing connection with MSSQL Server using mssql package node.js

Tags: sql-server, node.js

i am a new by to node.js and i am trying to connect with a test database on my local SQLExpress instance using mssql in node.js but i am stuck with the following error.

```
message: 'Port for SQLEXPRESS not found in ServerName;ComputerName;InstanceName;SQLEXPRESS;IsClustered;No;Version;12.0.2000.8;;'
    ,code: 'EINSTLOOKUP'
```

I have installed tedious and enabled by TCP/IP protocol in SQL Server Configuration Manager as well but it won`t work.
Here is my connection configuration

```
 var config = {
            user: 'sa',
            password: 'mypassword',
            server: 'ComupterName\\SQLEXPRESS',
            database: 'testdb',
            port: 1433
        };
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "app.js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm install express --save",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "Aamir",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "mssql": "^3.3.0",
    "tedious": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

Am i missing some configuration or is there any connection string related issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still a problem for you. Put SQL Server is being run as  service on your computer thus using localhost instead of your computer name would automatically resolve the request from the node process to your sql server service.

Let me know if this worked for you.

P.S Also I'm not sure if the node package mssql works for SQL Server Express since that is the free version. I know it works for SQL server since I use it at work.